# Getting null pointer exception in list Files method?

Tags: nullpointerexception, documentfile

I am trying to retrieve all `DocumentFile[]` using `listFiles()` method.But getting a null pointer exception how to eliminate this error and still get the files.
This is the code which searches sd card root directory which is being passed as  `documentfile` in method parameter.

```
  private List<DocumentFile> getListFiles2(DocumentFile docfile) {
        List<DocumentFile> inFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<DocumentFile> files = new LinkedList<>();


//  check error arising here
        files.addAll(Arrays.asList(docfile.listFiles()));


        while (!files.isEmpty()) {
            DocumentFile file = files.remove();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                files.addAll(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));

            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".bmp")
|| file.getName().endsWith(".gif")
                    || file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || file.getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                    || file.getName().endsWith(".png") 
           ) {
                inFiles.add(file);

            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }
```

Comment: any suggestion how to do that?